# What is the best way to do math inside LaTeX macros?

Tags: macros, environments, calculations

I'm interested in writing a little personal package (or sharing it if it's actually useful) to speed up typesetting Trigonometry. I'd like commands like

```
\triangle{\alpha}{\beta}{\theta}{a}{b}{c}{30}{60}{90}
%% (label angles, label sides, absolute angles)
```

to draw the simple drawings that worksheets/notes need over and over. In addition, I'd like commands such as `\solvedegtan{24}` to display `tan(24°) = 0.445` in the document.

I know I could probably accomplish this using `python.sty` (I've done that in the past) but what is the proper way to make LaTeX do the calculations for drawing (I'll do the actual drawing in TikZ) and solving?

Comment: From the top of my head, there is `trig.sty`, `tikz-euclide` ... and `Lua`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks! Any tips on what to read for how to use trig.sty?

Comment: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/trig.pdf

Comment: You might look at using sagetex from http://www.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based method for setting up the macro `\solvedegtan{24}`:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\solvedegtan[1]{%
    \directlua{ tex.sprint ( math.tan ( math.rad (#1) ) ) }}
\begin{document}
\solvedegtan{24}
\end{document}
```

---

When dealing with the `%` character, which is "special" to both TeX and Lua (but in different ways), it's possible to "escape" the percent character while using the `\directlua` function. However, it's generally more convenient, coding-wise, to load the `luacode` package and to set up separate Lua-side and TeX-side code blocks. (Within a `luacode` environment, only the `\` (backslash) character needs to be escaped.)

The following example illustrates the operation of the `string.format` function, set to show 5 digits after the decimal point. (The Lua function `string.format` is a front end to the `C` function `sprintf`; hence, rounding is applied if necessary.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function solvedegtan(x,prec)
    return( tex.sprint ( 
       string.format( "%."..prec.."f", math.tan ( math.rad (x) ) ) ) )
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\solvedegtan[2]{\directlua{ solvedegtan(#1,#2) }}

\begin{document}
\solvedegtan{24}{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had the feeling I'd end up learning Lua... I really wish PyTex was as good as LuaTeX seems... Any way to do it inside `TeX` or `LaTeX` though?

Comment: @ryan - There are various floating-point libraries that let you do trigonometric calculations within pdfLaTeX. One of the nice things about LuaLaTeX -- to me at least -- is that it's a superset of pdfLaTeX for the most part, i.e., apart from some things related to input encodings and font loading procedures. On top of that, you get access to Lua via a fairly simple interface. One such interface, the TeX-side macro `\directlua`, is used in the answer above; other interfaces exist as well.

Comment: LuaTex is pretty cool! I'm liking the Lua, just stuck on how to round numbers... How does the `%` symbol fit into all this, since LaTeX uses it for comments and Lua uses it for string comprehension?

Comment: @Ryan - I've provided an addendum to show how to set up separate Lua and TeX code blocks, so that it's straightforward to use the `%` symbol in its Lua sense without having to go through escape contortions.

Comment: Thank you, that's far superior to the solution I found using `luatextra` in this case.

Answer (score 14):

The `pgf` math routines loaded by `tikz` give pure LaTeX computations:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\solvedegtan[1]{\pgfmathparse{tan(#1)}\(
  \tan(#1^\circ) = \pgfmathresult \)}

\begin{document}

\solvedegtan{24}

\end{document}
```

There is also a fixed point arithmetic library that you should investigate and a math library for programmatic constructions.  Here is an example with the first library

[image: Sample fpa]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

\newcommand\solvedegtan[1]{\pgfkeys{/pgf/fixed point arithmetic}%
  \pgfmathparse{tan(#1)}\(
  \tan(#1^\circ) = \pgfmathresult \)}

\begin{document}

\solvedegtan{24}

\end{document}
```

And here is the original code use the `tikz` `math` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand\solvedegtan[1]{\(
  \tan(#1^\circ) = \tikzmath{ \t = tan(#1); print \t;} \)}

\begin{document}

\solvedegtan{24}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\pgfmathparse` perform truncation rather than rounding by default? Or, is the fact that the last digit that's shown is `2` rather `3` a result of lack of precision in the `tan` function?

Comment: @Mico I think it is lack of precision - as mentioned there is an `fpu` library one can load for better results.

Comment: `pgf` is sometimes fickle to work with (is it a string or a number?) but works well otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this implementation of `\solvedegtan` in every place TeX is expecting a decimal number, even in something like

```
\setlength{\textheight}{\solvedegtan{60}\textwidth}
```

Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\solvedegtan}{O{5}m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round ( tand (#2) , #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\tan 45^\circ=\solvedegtan{45}$

$\tan 88^\circ=\solvedegtan[2]{88}$

\end{document}
```

The optional argument tells the maximum number of decimal digits for rounding.

[image]

The advantage over the nice LuaTeX solution by Mico is that this works with any TeX engine.